# Android Volley POST not working

Tags: java, android, json, android-volley

I would include examples, but none of dozens of examples I have tried seem to work. If I try to use requestJsonObject, I get an error on the response saying that it can't put a JSONArray into a JSONObject. If I try to use JSONArray, it can't seem to handle a post parameters. I found a post that claimed they updated something to allow JSONObject to be passed into JSONArray, but can't find a damn thing anywhere as to where or how I get it in my code.
All that I want to do is send a simple restful post, and get a json response. I'm looking through post after post after post and I'm not familiar enough with java to understand some of these more complex answers, find ones with no parameters, or find ones that are trying to push a JSONObject into JsonArrayRequest (which throws an error for me)
How in the hell do you get it to work in android?!?! Here's the two methods I have tried

```
private void makeArrayRequest(String setSwitch)
{
    try {
        Map<String, String> params = new HashMap();
        params.put("func", setSwitch);
        JSONArray parameters = new JSONArray(params);

        DisplayToast("Sending: " + setSwitch);
        JsonArrayRequest jsonRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(
                Request.Method.POST, url, parameters,
                new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                        DisplayText("Response: " + response.toString());
                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        //error.printStackTrace();
                        DisplayText("Error:"+error.getMessage());
                    }
                }
        );
        Volley.newRequestQueue(this).add(jsonRequest);
    } catch(JSONException e) {
        // this ends up getting thrown because of the HASH input
        DisplayText("ArrErr:"+e.getMessage());
    }
}

private void makeObjectRequest(String setSwitch)
{
    DisplayToast("Sending: " + setSwitch);


    Map<String, String> params = new HashMap();
    params.put("func", setSwitch);

    JSONObject parameters = new JSONObject(params);

    JsonObjectRequest jsonRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(
            Request.Method.POST, url, parameters,
            new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    DisplayText("Response: " + response.toString());
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    //this ends up getting thrown because of JSONArray response?
                    DisplayText("Error:"+error.getMessage());
                }
            }
    );

    Volley.newRequestQueue(this).add(jsonRequest);
}
```

Comment: have you try StringRequest ? `https://developer.android.com/training/volley/simple.html`

Comment: The problem is that eventually I'm going to have this thing talking to an ESP8266 and the libraries on it are used specifically (the way REST is supposed to work) for various functions via POST/GET/DELETE/etc. So I need to figure out how to send such specific requests if possible.

Comment: esp8266 as host to your android device right? never try with this, so its there no response at all?

Comment: Actually, thinking about that gave me a clue. For testing I'm using an apache server and a php script. $_POST is empty. What kind of data/mime type does android use to send $_POST data? (I've run into something like this before and the data was coming in different than expected)

Comment: if you are testing with Apache is there no access log or error log? and `Request.Method.POST` you have declare don't act as post method?

Comment: This does give me one other question though. I recall the work-around when I ran into this before was to add an HTTP header to the POST output so PHP knew what kind of data it was getting. Is there any way to do that with JsonObjectRequest?

Comment: Does `new JSONArray(params);` compile? It shouldn't... You can't put a key-value pairing into an array

Comment: It seems to, but then exceptions out saying it wants a primitive. I found a couple of other posts customizing a request using the String method. So I guess if the ESP has a hard time with the content-type, I have alternatives to still use POST if I need to.

Answer (score 1):

The differences between the java and the PHP was the problem. PHP handles POST data differently and wasn't getting the values because of the way they were encoded.

The work-around is to decode them from php://input

```
$post = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"), true);
```

as outlined [here](http://androidprogamminghelpguide.blogspot.mx/2014/09/how-to-use-volley-and-php-post.html)

Comment: I think the last time I ran into that was going from the ESP8266 back to apache/php, so I'm pretty sure I can get the microcontroller to read them right! lol